# How can i convert text UTC to hex in PHP?

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am working now to send push in ios, it is working fine for me, but the issue is with the emoji, when i send the emoji, it doesn't render in emoji, I did googling it says you need to convert `\ud83d\ude04` ythis text to `\xf0\x9f\x98\x84` but i am not able to convert it, how can i convert into this text ? 
Can anyone please help to solve this issue ?

Comment: You shoulkd add a little more background information. One example of desired conversion is not enough to help you. Maybe a link to the web resource you found would be useful. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get an idea of how to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
$str = "\ud83d\ude04";

$replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,4})/i", "&#x$1;", $str);
$result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-16", "HTML-ENTITIES");
$result = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'utf-16');

$resultHex = unpack('H*', $result);
$resultHex = $resultHex[1];
$resultHexStr = '\x' . implode('\x', str_split($resultHex, 2));

echo 'result = ' . $result;
echo '<br>';
echo 'hex = ' . $resultHexStr;
```

Output:

```
result = 
hex = \xf0\x9f\x98\x84
```